# Why doesn't my linear layout match my parent height in listview?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I have the following code

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/itemLayoutView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/list_view_layout_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/list_view_layout_margin" 
    android:background="@color/yellow">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/itemLinearLayoutView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/gameNameView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="@dimen/game_list_text_size" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/gameCreationDateView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/gray"
            android:textSize="@dimen/small_text_size"
            android:textStyle="italic" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayoutView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/red"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/infoButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/info" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/deleteButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/delete" />
    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

The LinearLayout with id itemLinearLayoutView is the main layout that wrap everything in a row of listview. The problem I am having is that the second linear layout child does not take the height of the parent linear layout with id itemLinearLayoutView. Any solutions? or Problem with the code?

Comment: Why would it? It is set to `wrap_content` so it will take the height of its children, cumulative

Comment: Still if I change this    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayoutView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/red"
        android:orientation="horizontal" > it doesn't match the parent height.

Comment: Just correcting what I have in the question  android:layout_height is equal to "match_parent" in this case.

Comment: can you please explain what do you exactly want.?

Comment: in your code you use match_parent and for that layout Relative layout is parent, so it is matching with parent. but it seems that your requirement is different. So please elaborate it and if possible can you please add a screen shot as per your requirment.

Comment: Basically I have a listview. Each row is a relative layout. I want 2 layouts within relative layout to have the same height.

Comment: The part I dont get is that parent has the same height as 1 st linearlayout so should match parent call for 2nd linearlayout have the same height also?

Comment: If any of these answers helped solve your problem, can you accept one please?

Comment: Okay, now time to pick an answer, dude.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem lies here:

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

This needs to be changed to "match_parent" in the LinearLayout which you want to be the parent's size. Also, you said

```
the second linear layout child does not take the height of the parent linear layout
```

These two layouts are not parents and children to one another. The parent is your RelativeLayout and both of your LinearLayouts are equivalent children of that RelativeLayout. Maybe this will help you debug any further problems you encounter.

Comment: @Dr. Mobius has a perfect code example of what I tried to explain

Comment: Doesn't RelativeLayout take the height of the 1st linearlayout after the view are added?

Comment: No. Your RelativeLayout has height and width set to match_parent. Because the RelativeLayout is your root or base Layout, the match_parent fills the whole screen.

Comment: by the way the relative layout is in a listview, it just be as big as 1 row item.

Comment: I am just having problem matching the height of the 2nd linear layout to the height of the relative layout.

Answer (score 2):

just change the layout height to match parent . problem will be resolved.

```
  <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/itemLinearLayoutView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
  // use match_parent instead of wrap_content 
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
```

Comment: Nope that didn't work. the problem is not with this one. the problem is with the 2nd Linearlayout.

Comment: just set the other linear layout height to the match_parent and let me know if it resolves your problem.

Comment: Nope it didn't resolve the problem. Is there anyway to set the height of 2nd LinearLayout to Match the 1st LinearLayout without have to put 1 layout within another?

Comment: keep the first linear layout height with the wrap content and then set the second linear layout with the match parent then it will resolve.

Comment: @Hong I don't think so. You would have to do that manually and programmatically I believe.

Answer (score 1):

the layout needs to be nested within the first linear layout to take the parameters of it, and the value of the layout height needs to be changed. Code as Follows.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/itemLayoutView"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/list_view_layout_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/list_view_layout_margin" 
android:background="@color/yellow">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/itemLinearLayoutView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/gameNameView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="@dimen/game_list_text_size" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/gameCreationDateView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/gray"
        android:textSize="@dimen/small_text_size"
        android:textStyle="italic" />


<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayoutView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/red"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/infoButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/info" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/deleteButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/delete" />

</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Doesn't it take the property of parent of relative layout in my case? nested wouldn't work since linear layout has different orientation.

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/itemLinearLayoutView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" <!-- you should use match_parent here -->
    android:orientation="vertical" >
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// try this way i have used LinearLayout as parent rather than RelativeLayout
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/itemLayoutView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/list_view_layout_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/list_view_layout_margin"
    android:background="@color/yellow">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/itemLinearLayoutView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/gameNameView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="@dimen/game_list_text_size" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/gameCreationDateView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/gray"
            android:textSize="@dimen/small_text_size"
            android:textStyle="italic" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayoutView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:background="@color/red"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/infoButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/info" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/deleteButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/delete" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: No. I want the 2nd layout to be all the way on the right side.